# ASP.NET (Umbraco v7) Subdomain Header/Footer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am having an issue that I believe is pretty straight forward and something people must experience often, but I can't find the answer here on this forum. I have a www.mysite.com domain, as well as a few subdomain.mysite.com's as well. The subdomains all share the same look and feel as the home page so it would be most efficient to keep the navigation header and footer all on 1 template. In doing that, the subdomain navigation links and footer links are all throwing 404's as the template files have relative links.

Is there a way in Umbraco to link to the node ID rather than the URL?

I have tried the following:

```
<li><a href="{localLink:1288}">Resource center</a></li>
```

But even this still throws an error by trying to go to a URL, https://subdomain.mysite.com/%7BlocalLink:1288%7D

I have seen some references to something like a prettyURL or something like that? Is that suggested?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the structure of the Umbraco tree in the backend?

Comment: - Base template
   -- Interior page template
   -- Versions of interior pages


- Subdomain Base template
   -- Subdomain Interior page template
   -- Versions of subdomain interior pages


The idea here is that I would like to use the Base template for the subdomains as well to reduce the redundancy in work. The headers and footers all look the same

Comment: Can you please post a representation of your content structure in Umbraco - i.e., are the sub domains in their own tree?  And being Umbraco 7, are you using the default MVC or MasterPages for the templates?

Comment: I am a frontend guy so we have people dealing with the MVC side. At the top of my templates is @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage so I would assume MVC

Comment: In terms of template tree. You can see the document tree here: [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/366d6e4faa.png). I need to create a separate tree for my subdomains as the links in the standard base template are relative. For obvious reasons, I would like to link solely to the page node in the Base, so I can rid the template tree of the BaseSubdomain entirely.